# Is bitch in "Bitch please" a verb or a noun?

Tags: meaning, slang

Is "bitch" in "Bitch please" expression a verb or a noun?

Is it calling the listener a bitch as in "bitch, please" or is it some kind of provocation as in "bitch (more) please (I don't really care)"?

Comment: Without context, it could be either. If reliably punctuated, it's a verb without the comma, but in sloppy writing or spoken language you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a noun, calling the listener a "bitch". And as noted in a comment, a comma should be inserted.  In speech there are two intonation groups which justifies the use of a comma.

I hope it is clear that it would be very insulting to use it in most contexts.

Comment: This is correct; specifically, it's a direct address.